# Winjs - window.external.Notify is not working in x-ms-webview

Tags: javascript, webview, uwp, winjs, windows-10-mobile

I'm working on a UWP and I am using window.external.Notify to communicate with webview by js works great in Windows 10 mobile but the desktop version (debugging on my local computer) then webvew not send me the response

app.js

```
document.getElementById('webview').addEventListener('MSWebViewScriptNotify', function (e) {
        var value = JSON.parse(e.value);

        console.log(e);// never show something
}
```

http://mywebsite/script.js

```
window.external.notify('{"code": "funncionaaa"}');
```

Comment: Have you ruled out anything on your machine preventing the call from returning? Have you tried it on a different machine and network?

Comment: In my knowledge you have to add your website address in list of allowed websites in ApplicationContentUriRules section of the app manifest in order for window.external.notify to work. Did you do that? [More info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227713).

Comment: I made a demo, but didn't reproduce your problem. Could you please post the codes of your html and the js codes of your webview(`http://mywebsite/script.js` can't be opened)?  A sample through online repository also helps.

Comment: Are you using Navigate method to load page into webview? As I know in manifest it's possible to add https sites, but not http.

Comment: I have the URI allowed websites in the manifest, and in my site just i have the js: window.external.notify('{"code": "funncionaaa"}'); and its works for windows 10 mobile, but not for Desktop